# Grammaticality of "raise an email"

Tags: grammaticality, email

I work for an organization where almost everybody uses the term "raise an e-mail" when they want the attention of or to communicate with anybody, or when they want approval from an appropriate authority.

For example, when the line manager wants the attention of the juniors on a specific issue he says, "I have raised an e-mail about discipline; please follow that."

My question is about the term "raise an e-mail". Is it a correct term to use in such instances? If not, what term should be used?

Comment: There seem to be a few places on line that use "raise" with email. But it looks pretty unusual.

Comment: I'm not even sure what "raise an email" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Is this from a native speaker or just someone who learned English from other non-native speakers?

Comment: One of the references I found was from Lloyds of London, the venerable insurance company. So it might be a phrasing used by people who are used to things like "raise an invoice, "raise an order", etc. (Which only raises the question of why the verb "raise" is used in those contexts...)

Comment: It's possible to raise a lot of things: an alarm, a question, a white flag, a stink, chickens, the dead. So it's not terribly surprising that, within certain organizations, "raise an email" may be commonly used as a short form for "raise a point or issue by sending [one or more people] an email [message]." Until the usage becomes more widely established, however, the form will sound strange or simply wrong to people who are not habitués of one of the corporate vivariums where the usage is standard.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which English-speaking country you work in, nor the line of work - both of which *might* be relevant.  To my British ears, the expression sounds strange although I understand what it is intended to mean.  In pre-computing days, would anyone have referred to "raising a letter"?  I think not, so why should it be acceptable to "raise an e-mail"?

Comment: It seems as though it could be jargon.

Comment: Agreeing with @SvenYargs. Perhaps "raise an email" is a parallel construction to "raise a hand" (in the sense of a classroom, where the student is ready with an answer). And if you work for an organization that employs computer programmers, it might be a parallel construction to "raise an exception": interrupt the current thread of execution and instead handle an error.

Comment: While it does sound *weird*, natives wouldn’t find *raise a complaint* strange. It’s idiomatic.

Comment: A complication is that 'raised an email' has been used with the (probably legitimate) sense 'brought up the matter of an email [sent by X]': 'Mr Lloyd has previously rejected suggestions he gave special access and research to the Institute of Public Affairs after Labor senators last year raised an email he sent to a member of the group with an attachment showing what he described as "generous" provisions in public service enterprise agreements.' [[Canberra Times](https://www.canberratimes.com.au/story/6017381/pmc-withholds-john-lloyd-emails-due-to-possible-investigation/)].

Comment: Another complication is that 'acceptable in the loop', 'acceptable in general English usage' and 'grammatical' are far from being identical. 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' is famously grammatical but toxic.

Answer (score 1):

The verb “raise” can have a different meaning or sense, in that which means “communicate” to someone by phone or radio as outlined in the Cambridge Dictionary

> (B2 level) *raise* verb [T] (COMMUNICATE)
>
> to communicate with someone, especially by phone or radio:
>
> **’I've been trying to raise Jack/Tokyo all day.’** *

- This sentence does not mean the narrator is looking after a child as would what would be normally meant by “to raise a child/person”. If it had this meaning, it surely wouldn’t make sense.

So it means something along the lines of “to pass on an email/to convey information/to contact”.

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/raise

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the expression.

I also understand it to mean what you describe: to email somebody about something in order to get or provide clarification.

It likely has its source in the parallel expressions *raise your hand*, *raise a flag*, or *raise a point of order*. It's a way of *signalling* that you want somebody's attention about something.

While it's something that doesn't sound altogether strange to me, it's not an expression I would use myself.

Having said that, if everybody at your company uses the expression, then it has idiomatic use at your company. So, it's certainly appropriate within the context of you and your peers.

However, if you're looking for an alternative because you want to phrase it more naturally in *general*, then try:

> I have *sent* an email.
>   I am going to *send* an email.

Comment: Although anything that we say about it is bound to be guesswork, the example of the use of the phrase that is given in the question suggests that it might be a condensed version of 'to raise an issue by e-mail'.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a "contamination" from other constructs. It is a grammatical, but in my opinion, unusual construct.

Compare to

> How do I raise a complaint

From [link](https://en-betfair.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6158/~/how-do-i-raise-a-complaint%3F)

> Lawyers raise memo against ongoing detention of Darfuri sheikhs

From [link](https://www.dabangasudan.org/en/all-news/article/lawyers-raise-memo-against-ongoing-detention-of-darfuri-sheikhs)

And

> Murder in Ryan school: Parents raise memo with 13 demands; Principals assure action
>   From [link](https://newsable.asianetnews.com/india/murder-in-ryan-school-parents-raise-memo-with-13-demands-principals-assure-action)

Comment: What justification do we have for 'it is grammatical'? 'Raise a question' will doubtless be found in dictionary examples, but 'raise an enigma' is probably unacceptable. Many verbs have restricted sets of direct objects that are available 
 (especially metaphorical candidates).

Comment: Well, 'raise an enigma’ is grammatical, as are most or all phrases  'raise <noun phrase>' but probably meaningless, unless you are very creative with language.

Comment: OK; so 'grammatical', but OP asks whether it is acceptable. The examples you give seem to be from largely non-Anglophone countries. I'd say 'jargon at best, possible to misunderstand by those not in the loop, best avoided outside that loop' rather than 'unusual'.

Comment: You might be right. Indias largest common language is English so maybe it could be argued that the idiomatic  form is “acceptable”, whatever that means. English is not my native language so my view of it might be (probably is) wrong.

Comment: Unless tags are added, Indian English is not considered to be being discussed (as 'standard').